# What is a good contact pressure for bolting steel busbars onto steel battery terminals?

Tags: batteries, resistance, contact

I would like to achieve a good/low contact resistance. From other graphs I've seen for copper and aluminium, there's a point of diminishing returns regarding contact resistance vs contact pressure. I am looking for that value for steel to steel contact.
I imagine this depends on surface roughness too. The battery terminals are freshly machined and so have a low surface roughness. The busbars have been roughened up over years of usage.

Thanks

Comment: It probably depends on the steel--should we assume standard carbon steel, stainless steel, or some fancy alloy steel?

Comment: Hi @Hearth, please assume standard carbon steel; nothing fancy.

Comment: That's about the worst-case scenario, then, because carbon steel rusts, and rust is non-conductive. The parameters will vary *significantly* based on age, environment, and other factors.

Comment: What if we assume steel that has not rusted yet?